# JavaScript set text field to empty when hiding it

Tags: javascript

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to set the textID value to be empty.

```
    function toggle_visibility(id,textid) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       var f = document.getElementById(textid);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
          f.value="";
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

I am sure it must be something simple.

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: (because then you would have seen the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token else`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The if statements ends after ; if you don't put it in brackets {}

Correct if else:

```
if (e.style.display == 'block') { // Multi-line.
      e.style.display = 'none';
      f.value="";
  }
  else
      e.style.display = 'block'; // Single-line.
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that the lack of brackets can be used in single line if else statements, might be where OP picked up this style.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the braces to indicated that all the statements inside the braces need to be executed. Otherwise I think only the first statement gets executed, so the field is not cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Like NullPointerException said, the statement ends after one statement if you don't use `{ ... }`. I think for clarity sake, it's best practice to always use brackets, unless the whole `if .. else if ... else` statement is of one-liners.

The following all work, but the middle and last are, in my opinion, much easier to work with.

```
/* Hard to follow */
if (false) { // Do several things
    console.log("Multi");
}
else // Do one thing
    console.log("Singe");


/* Easy to see what's related to what */
if (false) {
    console.log("Multi_if");
}
else{
    console.log("Multi_else");
}


/* Reasonably clear to decipher */ 
if (false)
    console.log("Single_if");
else
    console.log("Singe_else");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/qGK7B/